# How add "jdbc" plug-in with gradle

Tags: java, scala, gradle, playframework

I've spend few hours try implement 
this sbt code `libraryDependencies += jdbc` for gradle.

I just want add database access in my app as described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.8/ScalaDatabase). And without that plug-in I not see *play.api.db.DB* class, only *play.api.db.Database* and *play.api.db.DBApi*.

Could someone help me?

I'm using Gradle 3.1, JDK1.8.0_05, Play!2.5.8, Scala2.11

Here is appropriate gradle code:

```
configurations {
    compile
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-jdbc-api_2.11', version: '2.5.8'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'anorm_2.11', version: '2.5.8'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-iteratees_2.11', version: '2.5.8'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.3-1100-jdbc4'
}
```

*UPDATE

I've also tried get database access using `@Inject(db: Database)`, but still get error, like figured on screenshot below:

[image]

So, I made mistyped: correct code - `@Inject()(db: Database)`

Comment: why don't you add it to the dependency as usual: dependencies {
       classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
  }

Comment: I did it, but problem not gone

Comment: You don't see the play.api.db.DB class because it was deprecated and it's possible that in the latests versions of Play framework it's not included anymore. It was deprecated and it was replaced by play.api.Database. Look at package summary https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/api/java/play/db/package-summary.html. Thefore upgrade the play framework to the latest: compile group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-jdbc-api_2.11', version: '2.5.8'

Comment: I've updated topic. It also not working for me.

Comment: Ohh, sorry! I made mistake

Comment: in the link you've pasted it says: The following code show you a JDBC example very simple, working with MySQL 5.*:

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to declare `Play!` dependencies in correct way as described in documentation: [Adding dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/play_plugin.html#sec:adding_dependencies). So you have to use `play` instead of `compile` for compile-time dependencies.

For example for Postgres DB the configuration could be following:

#### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "play"
    id "idea"
}

ext {
    playVersion = '2.5.8'
    scalaVersion = '2.11'
    javaVersion = '1.8'
    gradleVersion = '3.5'
}

model {
    components {
        play {
            platform play: playVersion, scala: scalaVersion, java: javaVersion
            injectedRoutesGenerator = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    play "com.typesafe.play:play-java_$scalaVersion:$playVersion"
    play "com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc-api_$scalaVersion:$playVersion"
    play "com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc_$scalaVersion:$playVersion"
    play "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1"

    playRun "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
}
```

#### application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://server_host:5432/db_name"
db.default.user=user_name
db.default.password=user_password
```

#### P.S.

`idea` gradle plugin is optional. But currently `play + gradle + idea` integration is not very good. That's why I have to invoke `gradlew cleanIdea idea` command from time to time just to include dependencies and sources into idea-project.

Currently I have following versions:

- `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4`
- `Gradle 3.5`
- `Play! 2.5.8`

I hope in future integration will be better than today.